# Popover bug in Edit Questions

Tags: bug, tags

When the tags are hovered, some times I am getting this way. This is the second time today:

> [image]

See the popover for the tag, it went somewhere out.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the SE image uploader? imgur delete images after a while, which leads to image rot - at some point, we'll have broken image, and nobody will be able to know what image you posted. Please start using it by clicking this icon: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pMd5j.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard Reason: Direct paste is not yet supported there. In imgur, I just `Ctrl + V`. If the images are deleted in some time, lemme check my first ever post where I used imgur. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It is supported, but only in Chrome. Even so, still better to take the imgur link and re-upload via "link from the web" in the SE uploader

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am using only Chrome. :D Okay then awesome. I will start using it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: So CTRL+V should work just fine in the SE uploader itself, I'm using it myself all the time. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just checked it. Thanks for that buddy. It is really hassle when I need to paste from imgur.com anyway. That's one best news I had. Let's not discuss about this further. Thanks.